# Is there any free program for making diagrams of file dependencies extracted from header files?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, file, dependencies, doxygen

Looking for something similar to Modelmaker that was for Delphi.
Showing dependecies of modules. Any help is appreciated.

Doxygen has been great so far. If someone know if it's possible to
achieve what I want with Doxygen, then please let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is [this](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_include_graph) what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for. Just tried it out, and it works like a charm. Doxygen keeps impressing me :) 

The output is so-so, but I guess I can get it to look how I want with a little tweaking. cinclude2dot looked promising too, also using graphviz.

Answer (score 0):

cube is right, i don't know much about other tools for dependency graphing, but imho doxygen will give more than that. Be aware, that doxygen need Graphviz for dependency graph option.
www.doxygen.org
www.graphviz.org

Alternative (perl script):
http://flourish.org/cinclude2dot/

Comment: Hmmm, didn't checked your comment on cube's post. sorry.